# How to display 24 hour format in DateTimePicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I'm using the Datetimepicker library.

This is my code, I have reviewed questions already raised but no solution works for me.

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: moment().add(1, 'd'), //defaultDate
    minDate: (fecha.getTime() + 1 * 86400000), //minDate
    disabledHours: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 21],
    locale: "es", //language
    format: 'Y/m/d A HH:mm', //format
    inline: true, //alignement
    sideBySide: true //visual Ubication
});
```

The recommendations say that I use `format: HH: mm`, instead of using `hh: mm`, but I use this and the change does not take effect.

Comment: Syntax error, your closing `})` is commented out. Please try an editor like vs code or Atom, that will tell you something is wrong immediately (shortest feedback loop). Or press F12 in the browser and see the error in the console.

Comment: Also; are you using [this one](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) it seems disabledHours is an undocumented feature.

Answer (score 0):

I had one more character in my code. format:

**'Y / m / d A HH: mm'**

to

**format: 'Y / m / d HH: mm'**